# What does two points mean in C #

Tags: c#

1. What does the question mark mean in isNew?
2. Tell me what the colon means before studentRepository ?

```cs
Student student = isNew ? new Student  
{  
    AddedDate = DateTime.UtcNow  
} : studentRepository.GetStudent(id.Value);
```

Comment: Google: ternary conditional operator, it is like if in short(inline) form.

Comment: ? is the ternary operator - see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Comment: `? :` is the ternary operator. I.e., `?` and `:` belong together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As C1sc0 said, this is the [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator).

Your code is equivalent to the following:

```
Student student;

if(isNew) {
    student = new Student { AddedDate = DateTime.UtcNow };
} else {
    student = studentRepository.GetStudent(id.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question makes little sense, as the ternary conditional operator (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) syntax is part of the language, and its parts have no separate meaning. `?` acts as an `if`, `:` as an `else`, but these are imperative concepts, while the operator is functional.